# Good Resource Loading System

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, resources

I'm currently looking for a resource management system for actionscript3. More specifically in this case, I'm looking for opinions on off-the-shelf resource loaders/managers from people who have used them,

- are they clean/simple to use?
- are they designed to be extended?
- I plan on using this with an MVC like system, Mate is next on the list, has anyone else used a resource loader in this manner?
- [masapi](http://code.google.com/p/masapi/)
- [queueloader](http://code.google.com/p/queueloader-as3/)
- [bulk-loader](http://code.google.com/p/bulk-loader/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been very happy with bulk-loader.  We've integrated it with Parsley's MVC and IoC frameworks - http://spicefactory.org/parsley/ - with great success.